# How to finish activity in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an fragment which added in Mainactivity in That fragment in onResume I send request to server ,problem is that when I press device back it will display a toast "pree again to exist " when I press again it will again resume and send server request instead of exist app .How can I resolve this problem.

code:-

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume.........");
    /*Registered Broadcast receiver*/
    IntentFilter m_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();// creating object of Intentfilter class user for defining permission
    m_intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");// action to check Internet connection
    getActivity().registerReceiver(m_oInternetChecker, m_intentFilter);// register receiver....

    getDetails();

}
private void getDetails() {// get details of user from shared preference...
    CLoginSessionManagement m_oSessionManagement = new CLoginSessionManagement(getActivity());// crating object of Login Session
    HashMap<String, String> user = m_oSessionManagement.getLoginDetails();// get String from Login Session
    m_szMobileNumber = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_MOBILE).trim();// getting password from saved preferences..........
    m_szEncryptedPassword = user.get(CLoginSessionManagement.s_szKEY_PASSWORD).trim();// getting mobile num from shared preferences...

    sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// increment of record count
    m_n_DeafalutLastCount = 0;
    sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// increment of last count...

    s_oDataset = new ArrayList<>();// making object of Arraylist


    if (NetworkUtil.isConnected(getActivity())) {
        m_NoInternetWarning.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        postDealListingDatatoServer();// here sending request in onCreate
    } else {
        m_NoInternetWarning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        m_BtnRetry.setEnabled(false);
        m_BtnRetry.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));// color of login button
        mSwipeRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        CMainActivity.this.finish();
        return;
    }
    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.pressagaintoexit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: You call `finish()` to kill an Activity, but I don't think that's your question, is it?

Comment: post your `onBackPressed()` code

Comment: try to kill activity like getActivity().finish();

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to finish `Activity`

- **If you are in `activity` itself**

  `finish()`
- **If you want to finish `Activity` from `Fragment`**

  `getActivity().finish()`
- **From other `class` or `Activity`**

  First in your `Activity` define a `Object` of your `Activity` type.

  `static Activity activity;`

  Now onCreate of this `Activity`

  `activity = this;`

  Now create a method `getInstance()` with return type `Activity`

  `public static Activity getInstace() {
      return activity;
  }`

  Now when you want finish activity call

  `Activity.getInstance().finish();`
- **Another way**

  `((ActivityName)context).finish();`

Comment: `static Activity activity`... Singletons? That doesn't seem like a good pattern to follow.

Answer (score -1):

**change**

```
CMainActivity.this.finish();
```

**to**

```
getActivity().finish();
```